Override autoref name for custom equation environment
I'm unable to get references made using \autoref from the hyperref package to a custom environment based on the equation environment to use a custom name. Instead of using the custom name, such references use "Equation".
Consider the following example:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

% Define a 'query' counter and environment, based on 'equation'
\newcounter{query}
\newenvironment{query}
{\refstepcounter{query}%
\renewcommand\theequation{Q\arabic{query}}\equation}
{\endequation}

% Attempt to override the name autoref uses for the query environment
\newcommand{\queryautorefname}{Query}

\begin{document}

A labelled instance of the query environment can be found below:
%
\begin{query}
    \label{q:my_query}
    Q(x) = ...
\end{query}

A reference to \autoref{q:my_query} using \texttt{autoref} uses the wrong name to refer to the environment (i.e., Equation rather than Query).

\end{document}


This issue (as described in the example) is that the reference made in this way will read "Equation Q1" where I would like it to read "Query Q1". What can I change in order to achieve this?
I'm open to a different strategy for getting this to work (for example, a different definition of the query environment), but it is important that the contents of the query environment be set to math-mode, and that the environment's counter is independent of other counters (such as the equation counter). Using cleveref rather than hyperref is problematic in this case, as it has caused me trouble in combination with the svjour3 template/document class which I am bound to use.

Welcome to TeX.SE!

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

% Define a 'query' counter and environment, based on 'equation'
\newcounter{query}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{query}
{\stepcounter{query}%
 \def\Hy@chapterstring{equation}%
 \def\Hy@chapapp{query}%
\renewcommand\theequation{Q\arabic{query}}\equation}
{\endequation}
\makeatother
% Attempt to override the name autoref uses for the query environment
\newcommand{\queryautorefname}{Query}

\begin{document}

A labelled instance of the query environment can be found below:
%
\begin{query}
    \label{q:my_query}
    Q(x) = ...
\end{query}

A reference to \autoref{q:my_query} using \texttt{autoref} uses the wrong name to refer to the environment (i.e., Equation rather than Query).

\end{document}



Thank you for providing a solution with minimal changes!
